# Juvenile SF series, 1970s, white covers with thin Futura text, female author?

Tags: story-identification

I remember a series of children's / juvenile SF books at my local library in the 1970s. Slim books, white spines, illustrated covers and some interior illustrations maybe, may not all be the same author but in my mind the name "Eve" seems to be attached - I had thought maybe Eve Bunting and/or Monica Hughes based on other searches, although none of their books that I can find match what I remember:

- Story about people on a spaceship going to colonize a new world, only realizing along the way that they have shrunk to live someplace smaller? - there was a mention of "R factor" meaning Reduction factor as part of the star drive system.
- Another story about an accident in a lab spilling a substance down a drain, which manages to somehow pollute the entire world; anyone who comes into contact with it dissolves rather horribly into red jelly.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The second one reminds me of Yahtzee Crowshaw's *Jam*.

Comment: Interesting, I don’t know that book. This would have been written more late 1960s-early 1970s and is either a short story in an anthology or a short juvenile SF novella.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first story can be "[The Island of One](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?81151)" by Eve Bunting

> When an asteroid threatens to destroy their space island, the sole
> survivors of the destruction of Earth must find a new place to go.

Quote from the [Google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=86akoWWXosAC):

> "There were nine hundred of us using up supplies faster than we could
> recreate them. Seth's father said it was a pity we weren't all
> smaller. We'd need less space, less food, less energy. Maybe all
> experiments start with crazy ideas." Seth was beginning to understand.
> "The R Factor. The Reduction Factor. If it worked we wouldn't even
> know. We'd all become small together. There would be no freaks."
> "Exactly."

I don't see which one (if any) could be the second story, but the other books from the "Creative science fiction" series are:
"Day of the Earthlings", "The Followers", "The Mask", "The Mirror Planet", "The Robot People", "The Space People" and "The Undersea People" (the same author).

Comment: That’s definitely it! Surprised that I couldn’t find it more easily.